# Code doesn't retrieve any key from .config file c#

Tags: c#, key, config

I have this code to get all the key/value from a custom `.config` file where I pass it's path, but the code retrieves 0 keys, I'm not understanding why.

Here's the code:

```
public void UpdateService(string FilePathOld, string FilePathNew)
{
    string[] Keys = { "SleepTimeInSeconds", "LogCleanInMinutes", "LogFileSize", "SqlTrans", "RemoteType", "DebugMode", "SleepError", "LogLevel", "LogSqlClient", "LogFile", "DebugRemote" };

    Dictionary<string, string> Old = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Dictionary<string, string> New = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    ExeConfigurationFileMap configOld = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
    configOld.ExeConfigFilename = FilePathOld;

    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configOld, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    ExeConfigurationFileMap configNew = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
    configNew.ExeConfigFilename = FilePathNew;

    Configuration config2 = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configNew, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings = config.AppSettings.Settings;
    Old = settings.AllKeys.ToDictionary(key => key, key => settings[key].Value);

    KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings2 = config2.AppSettings.Settings;
    New = settings2.AllKeys.ToDictionary(key => key, key => settings2[key].Value);
}
```

Comment: AppSettings or UserSettings or SomeOtherSettings? Are you checking under right node/setting name? If possible please show config file too.

Comment: I want to retrieve all the settings in the appSettings section.
here is the config file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByZb1KP9efohTDVhZXp1VkNBOEk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @touchofevil In the code I dont specify wich section I want. could it be that?

Comment: Code to do that looks okay if i replace the filepath. Check if filepath is correct. I did manage to get all 40 keys in the dictionaries.

Comment: @touchofevil you were right :D I was passing the wrong file path due to a change that I've done on the escape sequence. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access key value from web.config to your page like..

ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SleepTimeInSeconds"];

here "SleepTimeInSeconds" is your key & you get value using your key name

you have to write this code for all keys...

Comment: but I need to retrieve all keys and values from the .config to a dictionary as I did above. but the code doesnt return any key or value

Comment: I understand that, but I cant proceed like that because I can't know all the key names in the file, they may even be different. I need to return all of the keys wihtou specifing any key

Comment: What about ConfigurationManager.appSettings.Keys gets all Keys from appSettings and iterate all keys and use them.